# filter `id` with a specified value in another column and it does not appear more than once on each `id`

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having, conditional-aggregation

I have table `user`:

```
user_id  status
1010      1
1010      3
1010      3
1011      5
1011      2
1011      3
1012      3
1012      3
```

i want to filter `user_id` with the condition that the number "3" in the `status` column cannot appear more than once.

Expected output:

```
user_id
1011
```

I tried this query:

```
select * from (
    select user_id, status, 
    count(status) over (partition by status,user_id) as `sc` 
    from df
    )
    where sc<=1
    order by user_id
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM df
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(status = 3) <= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in MySQL HAVING and a conditional `SUM`

```
SELECT `user_id` FROM user GROUP BY user_id HAVING SUM(status=3) <= 1
```

| user_id |
| --- |
| 1011 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zw6OvvH1)